# Bootstrap 3 Multiple Date Validation

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap ver. 3 along with bootstrapValidator ver. 0.5.2 and Datetimepicker ver. 3. My problem is when I validate 3 dates next to each other the error message is above the first date, instead of where it should be. I know it has something to do with the fact that I'm using all 3 controls in the same form-group, but I don't know how to fix it. I have included a screen shot and code below. In the screen-shot I've included you can see that the popup is on top of 'Incident Date' and the cursor is in the 'Resolution Due Date'.

Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="*Required" name="txtTitle" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Incident Date:</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='dtpIncidentDate'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="*Required" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dtpNIncidentDate"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Date Assigned:</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='dtpDateAssigned'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="*Required" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" name="dtpNDateAssigned"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Resolution Due Date:</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='dtpResolutionDate'>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="*Required" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" name="dtpNResolutionDate"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#form1').bootstrapValidator({
    container:'popover',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        txtTitle: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The Title is required and cannot be empty'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,
                    message: 'The title can only consist of alphabetical and number'
                }
            }
        },
        dtpNIncidentDate: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Incident Date is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        },
        dtpNDateAssigned: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Date Assigned is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        },
        dtpNResolutionDate: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Resolution Date is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
$('#dtpIncidentDate')
    .on('dp.change dp.show', function (e) {
        // Revalidate the date when user change it
        $('#form1').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dtpNIncidentDate');
    });
$('#dtpDateAssigned')
    .on('dp.change dp.show', function (e) {
        // Revalidate the date when user change it
        $('#form1').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dtpNDateAssigned');
    });
$('#dtpResolutionDate')
    .on('dp.change dp.show', function (e) {
        // Revalidate the date when user change it
        $('#form1').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dtpNResolutionDate');
    });
```

});

[image]

Comment: Just a sugestion: use this http://jqueryvalidation.org for validation. It's better.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I moved the row above the form-group and everything is working like it should. Each 'X' is controlled by the form-group. Below is the new code just in case someone else has the same issue I am.

```
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Incident Date:</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='dtpIncidentDate'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="*Required" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dtpNIncidentDate"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Date Assigned:</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='dtpDateAssigned'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="*Required" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dtpNDateAssigned"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Resolution Due Date:</label>
                    <div class='input-group date' id='dtpResolutionDate'>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="*Required" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dtpNResolutionDate"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```